# Are $C^\infty$ Functions with all derivatives positive on [a,$\infty$),a$\gt$0 always made of exponential?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, analytic-functions

Are there any $C^\infty$ real functions except the exponential family and gamma function family which has all the derivatives of same sign on an interval [a,$\infty$) with a$\gt$0 ?
I speculate the function is always uses exponential as building blocks and it is unique defining property of exponential functions.

Please provide some instances otherwise.

I have not been able to find any so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose an arbitrary sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n \ge 0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = 0$. Then the power series
$$
 f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
$$
converges on  $\Bbb R$, is a $C^\infty$ function, and $f$ and all its derivatives are positive on $[0, \infty)$.

Examples are
$$
 \sinh(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \ldots \\
 \cosh(x) = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \ldots 
$$

Comment: @ShlokVaibhav Note that you can modify a couple of the $a_n$ in the beginning (say $a_1$ to $a_5$) in an arbitrary way and you will still get a function with your desired properties.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is necessarily a 'mixture' of exponentials. All you have to do is apply Bernstein's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions ) to $g(x)=f(-x)$. Thus $f(x)=\int e^{ax} dg(x)$ for some $g$.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a function other than exponential, I have edited the question to make my query clear.

Comment: Sir, I mean whether there is an example where exponential is avoided completely

Comment: @ShlokVaibhav Please take a look at my new answer. I think the other answer is misleading. The examples there (like $\sinh\, x$,$\cosh\, x$) are made up of exponentials.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I could not respond immediately due to exams going.

Comment: Some problem with your argument. You start with a function $f(x)$ with positive derivatives on $[0, \infty)$. Then $g(x) \colon = f(-x)$ will have derivatives of alternating signs on $(-\infty, 0]$. However, Bernstein theorem is about functions  on $[0, \infty)$.